# some router issues when using vue3 + vite to build

Tags: vue.js, iis, build, vuejs3, vite

I'm new in vue development. I currently build an app in IIS server. when using `npm run dev` to run in local it's correct. but when deploy in https://server_url/app_name, has an issue use https://server_url/app_name/index.html in browser, can display `<navigation-bar>` and `<footer-bar>` correctly, but the `<router-view>` is not default component. with https://server_url/app_name/ directly, the default component can be displayed correctly.
Here's App.vue

```
  <div class="container-fluid fixed-main-container" style="padding: 0;">
    <navigation-bar></navigation-bar> 
    <router-view></router-view>
    <footer-bar></footer-bar>
  </div>
</template>
```

router/index.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import About from '../components/about.vue'
import Index from '../components/index.vue'
import Intro from '../components/intro.vue'
const routerBase =  process.env.NODE_ENV==='development'? "": '/app_name/';
const routes=[
    {
        path: '/about',
        name: 'About',
        component:About,
        props: route => ({
          propOrgId: route.query.orgId,
          propStartDate: route.query.startDate,
          propEndDate: route.query.endDate
        }),
      },
      {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Index',
        component:Index,
        props: route => ({
          propOrgId: route.query.orgId,
          propStartDate: route.query.startDate,
          propEndDate: route.query.endDate
        }),
      },
      {
        path: '/intro',
        name: 'Intro',
        component:Intro,
        props: route => ({
          propOrgId: route.query.orgId,
          propStartDate: route.query.startDate,
          propEndDate: route.query.endDate
        })
      }
]
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(routerBase),
    routes
  })
export { router as default }
```

vite.config.js

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: process.env.NODE_ENV==='development'? "": '/app_name/',
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```

in main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue' 
import App from './App.vue'
import { default as router } from './router'

import { BootstrapVue3} from 'bootstrap-vue-3'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue-3/dist/bootstrap-vue-3.css'
const app = createApp(App);

app.use(BootstrapVue3)
app.use(router);
app.mount('#app');
```

the rewrite rule set in app_name is
(1) url path after '/app_url/' matches ".*" (2) {REQUEST_FILENAME} is not a file (3) {REQUEST_FILENAME} is not a directory
the rewrite url is index.html
in web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Vue Router Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You will have to edit the question to include your IIS settings, such as the IIS URL rewrite rules in `web.config`.

Comment: @LexLi Thank you for your reminder! I set up the rewrite url through IIS UI before, but after checking the web.config, I found that the pattern was wrong. After modification, most of the issues have been resolved, but there are still issues that have not been solved.

Comment: "_most of the issues have been resolved, but there are still issues that have not been solved_"... Please be more specific.  Do you still need help?  What issues were fixed and which issues still need solving?  Update your question with these details.

Comment: @yoduh Thank ypu for the reply, I have update my issue. Now the issue is https://server_url/app_name/index.html not showing the default <router-view>

Comment: As far as I know, this is usually rewrite the url to `/` to match the route configuration of vue.js. Something like this: `<action type="Rewrite" url="/" ... />`. Does this work for you?